# Dynamically create variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I want to create 1 variable name, but part of the name is the value stored in `$i`. Same for the GET result:

```
$Site.$i = $_GET['site'.$i]; // Should look something like $Site1 = $GET['site1'];
```

Please help me understand how to do this.

Comment: This is doable, but generally a terrible idea.

Comment: I realise that, better to add to an array???

Comment: array -> yes it IS way better, I highly recommend that rather than variable variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a set of related variables, use an array:

```
$site[ $i ] = $_GET['site'.$i];
```

Even better, your GET parameters can also be an array

**HTML**

```
<input name="site[foo]" value="bar" />
```

**PHP**

```
$site = $_GET[ "site" ];

print_r( $site );
```

**output**

```
$site = array(
  "foo" => "bar"
)
```

If you want the indexes for the array to decided automatically then you can do

```
<input name="site[]" value="foo" />
<input name="site[]" value="bar" />
<input name="site[]" value="baz" />
```

and get `$_GET[ "site" ]` out as

```
$site = array(
  0 => "foo",
  1 => "bar",
  2 => "baz"
);
```

Comment: +1 This is the most logical/cleanest alternative. Thanks for expanding the point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199744/dynamically-create-variables-in-php/6199767#6199767

Answer (score 2):

### Direct Answer to Question

This is how you can do it. Not the best idea however.

```
$var = "$Site$i";
$$var = $_GET['site'.$i];
```

This makes use of [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

### Alternative Maintaining Current URL Structure

Alternatively perhaps something like this might work for you:

```
$vars = array();
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(0 === strpos($key, 'site')) { // Only grab value if the key is prefaced by the string 'site'
        // You must sanitise the value some way here eg:
        // $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $vars[] = $value;
    }
}
```

See [filter_var() man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for more information on PHP filters and sanitisation/validation.

### Revised URL Structure

I think this probably best solved however by making use of HTML arrays at the point your URL is generated. For more information on HTML arrays please see the [PHP man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

This allows you to access your information like the following:

```
$site1 = $_GET['site'][0];
$site2 = $_GET['site'][4];
```

This is the most logical method of dealing with this situation.

**Update** also see [@Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199744/dynamically-create-variables-in-php/6199877#6199877) for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea for several reasons:

- You have to loop through $_GET to find all variables (there's no language construct to pattern-match them)
- Dynamic variables names are confusing, and may open security holes.

You will find that using an array will solve the second point, and also make it a lot easier to work with the code.

The first point can be solved by only using variable names you know. Send a variable containing a count how how many "sites" there are, for example:

```
site1=example&site2=example2&sitecount=2
```

This way you know that you only need to read `site1` and `site2`, and you donät need to examine any other GET variables.

Comment: I think HTML arrays are a better alternative than a count parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199744/dynamically-create-variables-in-php/6199767#6199767

Answer (score 0):

you van use  $ as $_GLOBAL like this.

```
${'Site' . $i} = $_GET['site' . $i];
```

or you can use [extract](http://php.net/extract)

please read the warnings about exract.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable variables like this:

```
$varname = $Site.$i;
$$varname = $_GET['site'.$i];
```

Doing this is discouraged however, because this is a huge security risk. You may write classes with fields representing your values from `$_GET` and validating them within the class.